# How to align a checkbox and a form horizontally?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a form and have a checkbox next to it. Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

So, the checkbox aligns with the form's label i.e. they are aligned at top but I would like to have both aligned at bottom.

How should this be done?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="text-muted">Select something!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
          <label for="some_selection">Select something</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="some_selection">
            <option selected>--None--</option>
            <option>foo</option>
            <option>bar</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="some_id">I should be far lower
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h3 class="text-muted">Select something!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
      <label for="some_selection">Select something</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">

    <select class="form-control" id="some_selection">
      <option selected>--None--</option>
      <option>foo</option>
      <option>bar</option>
    </select>

  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="some_id">I should be far lower
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks better than before (upvoted), however, now the label for the dropdown seems to be further away from the form than before and the checkbox is centered rather than aligned with the bottom. Any ideas?

Comment: Take the form-group class off the div that holds the label and that will bring it down. (Or change the .form-group margin-bottom to desired size in CSS; it's currently set to 15px)

Comment: And if you need the checkbox to be aligned with the bottom of the dropdown you'll want to make the height similar. I recommend setting the `margin-top` of your checkbox to 22px. That seems to work best to me. You can add a class/id to it and fix it in an external css file or just add `style="margin-top:22px"` to your input element